# Few things about USB 3.0 AND USB 2.0 speed?

Tags: usb, flash, usb-3

I have question about USB 3.0 and USB 2.0.

1) For example, a motherboard we have has 4 USB ports on the back.
Does that mean every USB port has 480 Mbits bandwidth, or are they connected onboard using a built-in USB hub so all of them have 480 Mbits?

2) When I get a USB 3.0 controller, and plug a USB 3.0 hub into that controller that has 4 USB 3.0 ports and get 12 USB 2.0 flash drives, each set of three plugged into a USB 2.0 hub and plug those 4 USB 2.0 hubs into 4 USB 3.0 ports. Will all flash drives work at FULL USB 2.0 speed? Or will all USB busses share a single USB 2.0 plug's worth of bandwidth?

[image: Graph showing 12 USB 2.0 drives, 4 USB 2.0 hubs, and a USB 3.0 controller in the topology as described above.]

Comment: I hope someone edit my post, to show picture.
I don't have right to do this...
I have right to upload, but not show... wired

Comment: We are a helpful bunch huh?

Comment: I have a related question if someone is interested in answering: [Maximizing speed of USB 2.0 clients on USB 3.0 hub](http://superuser.com/questions/1074183/maximizing-speed-of-usb-2-0-clients-on-usb-3-0-hub)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bandwidth is per Controller.

[Per MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff540194.aspx)

> A transfer takes place every time data is moved between the host
>   controller and the USB device. In general, USB transfers can be
>   broadly categorized into control transfers and data transfers. All USB
>   devices must support control transfers and can support endpoints for
>   data transfers. Each type of transfer is associated with the type of
>   USB endpoint (a buffer in the device). Control transfer is associated
>   with the default endpoint and data transfers use unidirectional
>   endpoints. The data transfer types use interrupt, bulk, and
>   isochronous endpoints. The USB driver stack creates a communication
>   channel called a pipe for each endpoint supported by the device. One
>   end of the pipe is the device's endpoint. The other end of the pipe is
>   always the host controller.

A connection with the USB device is to the USB controller. A device
 may also use as much bandwidth as they want. So thus the bandwidth is
 per controller.

**edit**

USB 3.0 Controllers will have both a USB 2.0 **and** and USB 3.0 controller.  So USB 3 devices will not be affected by USB 2.0 devices when connected to the same controller.

Now lets see if I can find a reference in Wikipedia for this. . .

**edit2**

[USB 3.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB)

> For SuperSpeed USB (defined since USB 3.0), connected devices can
>   request service from host. Because there are two separate controllers
>   in each USB 3.0 host, USB 3.0 devices will transmit and receive at USB
>   3.0 data rates regardless of USB 2.0 or earlier devices connected to
>   that host. Operating data rates for them will be set in the legacy
>   manner.

Comment: Great, so first question is done.

Comment: What about second, do i will have full usb 2.0 speed on all USB sticks ?

Comment: Ah forgot about the second question.

Comment: So, this will won't work in that way i show. Right ? I will got 480 mbit/s to share with all devices ?  It's sad :-(

Comment: @marc It's even worse. If I remember correctly, the controller in order to pass certification needs to provide around 50% of the bandwidth continuously!

Comment: Sad, sad...  anyway thank You all for responses. I marked that answer as correct because have many information.  Sad there is no USB Stick -> Sata adapter :-(